# Android wear get battery life of wearable

Tags: android, wear-os

Is there any way to get the battery life of a connected wearable? I've looked through the documentation but there doesn't seem to be anything that mentions battery life lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an app running on a phone, it is not possible to retrieve information about the battery state of a connected Wearable.

However, you can certainly [create a Wearable app](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) (which would get [packaged with your phone app](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) and auto-installed alongside your phone app) that would run on the connected device. You can then use the normal methods for [monitoring the battery life](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) directly on the Wearable, sending the results over to your phone app via the [Wearable data layer](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html).